# Trying to build AN API by connecting frontend (Flutter) to backend (Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, port, vscode-debugger

So right now I am trying connect the backend (Node.JS) to the frontend (Flutter). But I'm not able to, I just get a connection error. I believe this has to do with the fact that the terminal isn't specifying which PORT (3000) my node.JS app is listening on. Before when I would run 'npm start', it would show that it was listening on PORT 3000, now when I run it, it just says that it's successfully connected to MongoDB.

As far as I can tell, there are no errors in my entry point index.js or Flutter (main.dart). Oddly enough, I am able to open the login screen in the Xcode iOS simulator, but it's not working properly. I will send screenshots of everything. Here is the codes for main.dart

I would copy and paste the code for main.dart and index.js but stack overflow has really dumb formatting rules

Please any of help, I've been stuck on this for days, I even forwarded PORT 3000 with no success.

I tried running 'npm start' every time and all it shows me is that MongoDB is connected. It doesn't show anything regarding PORT. I was trying to use nodeMail for userMail in both main files, but I removed them because I was facing to many issues.

Now I'm going through index.js for each line of code to make sure I didn't do anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can check,

**1.Server Code:** Verify the code in your Node.js server where the port is specified. Look for something like this:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; // This line specifies the port
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Ensure that the server is indeed set to listen on port 3000 or check if it's using a different port specified in an environment variable (like process.env.PORT).

**2.Terminal Output:** If your server code should log the port upon starting, but it's not doing so, there might be an issue with the logging configurations or the server might not be reaching that point due to an error. Check your terminal logs for any errors or warnings that might prevent the server from starting correctly.

**3.Environment Variables:** Verify if there are any changes in your environment configurations or scripts that might be affecting the port assignment or the server start command (npm start). There could be a chance that the port configuration is now being set differently.

**4.Networking:** Ensure that there are no network-related issues preventing the connection. Sometimes firewalls or other network configurations might block the communication between the backend and frontend.

5.Flutter side url mistake, you can not use localhost for you'r url like bellow,

```
final loginUrl = Uri.parse('http://localhost:3000/api/user/loginUser');
```

use ip instance of localhost like bellow code segment,

```
final loginUrl = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/user/loginUser');
```

Try those solutions for fix your issue.

Comment: I will try that for sure, thank you. I need to get my server up and running first so that it's running on PORT 3000 before I can get started on connecting Flutter to Node.JS via REST API

Comment: My index.js is too long to paste here. But I'm still getting errors regarding PORT 3000. Not sure what you mean by Terminal Output or other Environmental Variables. The thing is, it is connected to MongoDB when I run 'npm start', so I don't know why it's not listening to the PORT I set up in index.js towards the bottom, I used that exact same code you pasted.

Comment: Do you use another medium besides SO or do you have an email where I can send you the code for index.JS and main.dart? It would make this a lot easier for both of us. SO won't accept the format of my body code

Comment: could you pleace give error message given from nodejs side

Comment: you can make git hub repo and keep on git hub

Comment: I have a github account. Do you want the URL link to my Git repo?

Comment: So there are no errors on the server side, that is In index.js. It is connected to MongoDB. I want to know how to get my app listening on PORT 3000 so when I hit 'npm start', it'll show that

Comment: I wil give answer wait

Comment: Okay, I apologize. Thank you

Comment: Actually I have my Git repo set to private on Github as I have my own API, in particular the MongoDB database password inside index.js. So you probably won't be able to view the files of my project anyway

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't mention this before, but the message I get in the terminal when I run 'npm start' is "(node: 1498) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The 'punycode' module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead". But I can send you the code for index.js and main.dart but you can't view my local repo via Github, because it is private not publilc